# How to calculate average of time with respect to midnight in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, data-analysis, sql-function

I have below data - I need to calculate the average of this times with respect to midnight time in SQL, Can you please tell me how should I calculate? If I convert them in seconds and simply take average I get ans as : 10:17:20 which is wrong . I need ans should be somewhere near to  23:00

```
0:06:43
0:10:26
0:12:49
0:18:21
0:19:35
0:22:40
1:57:01
2:21:41
15:56:12
16:40:22
21:31:45
23:26:56
23:38:29
23:38:30
23:38:33
```

Consider this small example. - my data is

```
2:21:41
0:19:35
0:18:21
23:38:33
```

for this I should get the ans as 00:30 ... Can you please let me know how I should calculate this in SQL?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "with respect to midnight", but I presume (from the answer you're expecting in your example) that you mean the interval to the nearest midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to change `time` to `interval`. This way you can *shift* your values to be *around midnight* by having negative values:

```
CASE WHEN value > '12:00:00' THEN value - time '24:00' ELSE value - time '00:00' END
```

See `time - time` operator in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html).

You'll get:

```
00:06:43    ->   00:06:43
00:10:26    ->   00:10:26
00:12:49    ->   00:12:49
00:18:21    ->   00:18:21
00:19:35    ->   00:19:35
00:22:40    ->   00:22:40
01:57:01    ->   01:57:01
02:21:41    ->   02:21:41
15:56:12    ->  -08:03:48
16:40:22    ->  -07:19:38
21:31:45    ->  -02:28:15
23:26:56    ->  -00:33:04
23:38:29    ->  -00:21:31
23:38:30    ->  -00:21:30
23:38:33    ->  -00:21:27
```

Now you can calculate average value. For the data specified you'll get `-00:54:39.8` which is `23:05:20.2` (for negative value you need to `+ time '24:00'`).

So, the final formula is:

```
AVG(
    CASE WHEN value > '12:00:00' THEN value - time '24:00' ELSE value - time '00:00' END
) + time '24:00'
```

You can always do `+ time '24:00'` because time will be wrapped if exceeds 24h.